# How to get website directory in SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, babun

My domain is set up with AWS, and I connected it with an EC2 instance so I can use SSH to build it (nginx is installed). But when I connect to the SSH server and use the `ls` command, the directory that would be my site does not show up. I do know from experience that the site should show up as a directory from a friend's server I have access to. Another note, I am using Babun as the command line for SSH.

Comment: Kinda ot for here. Maybe server fault be better.  Your web root is where every you installed it. Or wherever the package of Ngnix put it.  Look at your configuration files that should tell you where to look. Could be something like /var/www   When you ssh in you are in the home directory of your user.

Comment: When I typed ls, no files come up

Comment: Which means there are no files in the cwd.  You will need to change the directory. If you are not familiar with commands like cd  and pwd you should look for a tutorial on navigating via the command line.  You can try something like:  find / -name www   To look for files named www, but as there are many different ways to setup an instance it is impossible to give you exact answers.

Comment: For clarity I set up my EC2 following this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHuQExY360I&index=4&t=121s&list=WL)